# php how to parse xml with xml-namespces using SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, xml-namespaces

i'm trying to parse a xml file from soap api using Simplexml in php and i have problems with the namespaces in the xml file.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns="http://api.test.no/webservices">
  <xs:schema id="VismaBusiness" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="VismaBusiness" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Products" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Products">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ProductNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="WebIngress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="OriginalNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="UOM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="QtyPerUOM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="WeightUOM" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="LengthUOM" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="WidthUOM" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="HeightUOM" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="BarCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Brand" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SubCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="IsMainProduct" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MainProductNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SRP" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="StockBalance" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SortOrder" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ProductStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ETA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <VismaBusiness xmlns="">
      <Products diffgr:id="Products1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ProductNo>2326935</ProductNo>
        <Description>Deckvest Vito 170N Hammar Lifejacket</Description>
        <WebIngress xml:space="preserve"> </WebIngress>
        <OriginalNo>DW-VT/H170</OriginalNo>
        <UOM>Stk</UOM>
        <QtyPerUOM xml:space="preserve"> </QtyPerUOM>
        <WeightUOM>1.500000</WeightUOM>
        <LengthUOM>100.000000</LengthUOM>
        <WidthUOM>400.000000</WidthUOM>
        <HeightUOM>490.000000</HeightUOM>
        <BarCode>5025138507219</BarCode>
        <Brand>Spinlock</Brand>
        <Category>Sikkerhetsutstyr</Category>
        <SubCategory>Redningsvester/Flytevester</SubCategory>
        <IsMainProduct>0</IsMainProduct>
        <MainProductNo>H2326935</MainProductNo>
        <SRP>4899.000000</SRP>
        <StockBalance>0</StockBalance>
        <SortOrder>70050420</SortOrder>
        <ProductStatus />
        <ETA>2022-04-25</ETA>
      </Products>
    </VismaBusiness>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

Example of what i have tried(it works as it should if i remove the xml namespaces):

```
namespace Flak\Xml\FlakXmlParser;

class FlakXmlParser
{
    private $xmlFile;
    private $xml;

    public function __construct($xmlFile)
    {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $this->xmlFile = $xmlFile;
    }

    public function loadFile()
    {
        $file = file_get_contents($this->xmlFile);
        $this->xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($file);
    }

    public function productXmlToArray($node = 'VismaBusiness')
    {
        $this->xml = $this->xml->$node;
        foreach ($this->xml->Products as $xmlObject) {
            $products[(string) $xmlObject->ProductNo] = [
                'sku' => (string) $xmlObject->ProductNo,
            ];
        }

        return $products;
    }
}
```

It works if the xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns="http://api.test.no/webservices">
    <VismaBusiness xmlns="">
      <Products diffgr:id="Products1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ProductNo>2326935</ProductNo>
        <Description>Deckvest Vito 170N Hammar Lifejacket</Description>
        <WebIngress xml:space="preserve"> </WebIngress>
        <OriginalNo>DW-VT/H170</OriginalNo>
        <UOM>Stk</UOM>
        <QtyPerUOM xml:space="preserve"> </QtyPerUOM>
        <WeightUOM>1.500000</WeightUOM>
        <LengthUOM>100.000000</LengthUOM>
        <WidthUOM>400.000000</WidthUOM>
        <HeightUOM>490.000000</HeightUOM>
        <BarCode>5025138507219</BarCode>
        <Brand>Spinlock</Brand>
        <Category>Sikkerhetsutstyr</Category>
        <SubCategory>Redningsvester/Flytevester</SubCategory>
        <IsMainProduct>0</IsMainProduct>
        <MainProductNo>H2326935</MainProductNo>
        <SRP>4899.000000</SRP>
        <StockBalance>0</StockBalance>
        <SortOrder>70050420</SortOrder>
        <ProductStatus />
        <ETA>2022-04-25</ETA>
      </Products>
    </VismaBusiness>
</DataTable>
```

Does anyone have any ideas/solutions that might work?

Comment: You can use [children()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have tried it without success. Have also tested registerXPathNamespace and addChild..

Comment: Your code doesn't have any usage for `->child()` method. Can you please edit the question and show your attempt?